# How to separate number with commas in Thymeleaf

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

How to display Number with comma every 3 numbers in Thymeleaf?

For example, `12345678` I want to display this number as `12,345,678` . I got my data from Spring Boot

```
<div class="value" th:text="${price}"></div>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can try this way:

```
<div class="value" th:text="${#numbers.formatDecimal(price, 0, 'COMMA', 0, 'POINT')}"></div>
```

Comment: you save me, Thanks :)